# Why am I getting an error when trying to add an action listener to a button?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Sorry last program had lot of errors (i forgot to save the file and hence posted a incomplete code) so i am posting this

Here is the Code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIPreparedStatement {
    private JFrame frame1;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JTextField tf1;
    private JTextField tf2;
    private JButton b1;
    public JLabel lb1;
    PreparedStatement ps;

    GUIPreparedStatement() {
        frame1 = new JFrame();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        tf1 = new JTextField(10);
        tf2 = new JTextField(10);
        b1 = new JButton("Enter Record");
        lb1 = new JLabel("Press the Button");

        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Employees");
            ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(?,?)");
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            lb1.setText("SQL Statement not executed");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            lb1.setText("General Error");
        }

        b1.addActionListener(this);

        panel1.add(tf1);
        panel1.add(tf2);
        panel1.add(b1);
        panel1.add(lb1);

        Container contentPane = frame1.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(panel1);

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.pack();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            try {
                ps.setString(1,tf1.getText());
                ps.setString(2,tf2.getText());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException f) {
                lb1.setText("SQL Record not Entered");
            }       
        }
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new GUIPreparedStatement();
    }
}
```

Error in code:

http://screensnapr.com/u/nx5t1r.png

Comment: Fixed the title text and cleaned up the code sample.

Comment: -1 This question was fundamentally changed by the OP after I posted an answer which got +4.  Thanks for the "Disciplined" badge.

Comment: In the future, when something like this happens, close the first question and open a new one.  Do not edit your question and change the fundamental nature of the problem once it's been answered.

Comment: I was not able to close or delete or add comment yesterday ..so i had no other way except editing it. And oh yeah i tried to close this post at the first place but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your heavily edited question, your GUIPreparedStatment needs to implement the ActionListener interface.

```
public class GUIPreparedStatement implements ActionListener
```

Whilst you have already implemented the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` you have not declared to the compiler that you've done this to satisfy the interface contract.

Comment: Is there a another way to do this without implementing  action-listener.

Comment: You could move the actionPerformed method out into an anonymous inner class that implements ActionListener. But if you want to listen for an action, you need an ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your your errors are referencing lines of code which you did not post.

**EDIT:** Corrected assumptions which were invalid

Comment: Those undefined ps vars I'm willing to wager are PreparedStatements. Not sure a -1 was in order...but if you feel the need...

Comment: @Aaron: Most of the warnings are about undefined variables. Linking or similar things will not fix the error.

Comment: There are however serious errors in how JDBC is used. But that's indeed beyond the scope of the *actual* problem/question.

Comment: Just FYI - I removed by -1 once the question changed and the answer changed.  I think it was appropriate for the first answer, which missed the mark.  But now everything misses the mark through no fault of anyone's except the OP.